# How to replace row data based off the value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way so that when i load a csv file into a pandas df I can run a script that will go through the Description column and change the value if a condition is met. Example, if the the value in the description column  has the word x in it, will then replace that value with y and continue through that column and do it for multiple values.

Im not sure if this would be better an if..elif..else statement or better to locate buy row and then build a function.

```
data.loc[(data.Description == 'x'),'Description']= 'y'
```

But im not sure of the code to do a like statement in sql, for pandas.
I was trying `data.loc['indexes'] == data.Description.str.contains("x"), 'Description' = 'y'` but i couldnt get it to work

Comment: what your sample data ?

Answer (score 4):

You can check with

```
data.loc[data.Description.str.contains("x"), 'Description'] = 'y'
```

Comment: Sorry i was late to post, yours is the best and should be accepted

Comment: @WasifHasan no worry we are not speed racing , but help , aren't we :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `.str.contains()`:

```
data.loc[(data['Description'].str.contains('x')),'Description'] = 'Description'
```

Comment: It's funny I was looking to use `str.contains()` in a somewhat similar context.  Question:  Is that generally the most efficient way to do that sort off lookup on the table?